# old instances in box.info.vclock

Tags: tarantool

Good afternoon, I can’t clean  old instaces in box.info.vclock. 
Now I have cluster (master id = 3 / slave id = 4) and in `box.info.vclock` contains old instences (id = 1 and id = 2) which I deleted a long time ago (removed from the `box.space._cluster` and `box.cfg.replication`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log sequence number values are never deleted from vclock, even when the corresponding instance is removed from the cluster. This is done to make sure vclock always grows monotonically. An instance vclock component will be re-used when a new instance is added, (different instance uuid, but re-used instance id), in which case this instance will start counting its local changes from this component's value.